# Как выбрать кометарии из текста, и почистить результат?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В общем есть текст:

```
 ывадлолдывоа ьячсфыуа
 ываываыв
 ываываыва

  /*
   * Некий коментарий
   *
   */

      var reg = /\/\*([\s\S]+?)\*\//gi;

        rez=contents.match(reg);
        rez.forEach((item)=>{
          console.log(item);
        });
```

Вот такое регулярное выражение не находит ничего Почему??

```
      var reg = /\/\*(?:[\/\*])([\s\S]+?)\*\//ig;

      while (rez=reg.exec(contents)){
           console.log(rez);
       }
```

Результат хотелось бы получить вот такой:

> Некий комментарий

нужна помощь с регулярным выражением.

На данный момент получилось вот так:

```
* Некий комментарий
```

Comment: приведенная регулярка это часть текста или пример решения?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989315/regex-for-match-replacing-javascript-comments-both-multiline-and-inline

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/comment-regex

Comment: var reg = /\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*?\*\//g; вот такое регулярное выражение почему то не находит ничего. вернее находит null